# Basic analysis (calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this problem correctly or not interpreting some of the statements correctly. What I think it is asking is to prove that all the statements are equal to each other and if they are equal to each other then they imply each other. But I also don't understand some of the statements like (5) and (3). So I just need some clarification of the problem.[image: problem]

Comment: (3) means that the $c$ is greater than the distance between $a$ and $b$. (5) means that $c$ lies between the greater value of $b-a$ or $a-b$ and positive infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are asked to show that some set of $n$ statements $S_i$ are equivalent to each other, you are being asked to prove the implications
$$
S_1 \implies S_2 \implies \dotsb \implies S_n \implies S_1
$$
or
$$
S_1 \iff S_2 \iff \dotsb \iff S_n.
$$
In other words, a given statement implies every other statement and every other statement implies the given statement.

In your case, statement $(3)$ says that $c$ is greater than the distance between $a$ and $b$, as *Lovsovs* noted, and $(5)$ says that $c$ is in the open interval bounded below by the maximum of the two values $a - b$ or $b -a$ and is bounded above by $\infty$.